# Reading graphs and analyzing them

Tags: python

I know we can load a CSV file and use matplotlib or seaborn libraries to plot graphs and analyse them. But is there any way we can read graphs that are outputs of another program using the subprocess library, or is there any other library to do this?

Basically, what im asked to do is i need to create a program that automatically detects small patterns like most frequently occurring data w.r.t timestamps, etc.

Based on my research, im getting results only on how to plot graphs rather than reading them as input.

Comment: Please clarify what do you mean by graph; Is it a structure consisting of nodes and edges or do you mean plot of function (e.g. in matplotlib)?

Comment: Scatter or bar plots of function

Comment: This looks like machine learning? Take a look at `sklearn`. It has an example that shows how to classify images of hand-written numbers. That sounds very similar to what you have in mind.